# Using SupportMapFragment in Activity instead of FragmentActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using SupportMapFragment to show the google map in my activity. But the activity must be declared as FragmentActivity. Is there any way to use it in Activity instead of FragmentActivity? Here is my work:

In xml, I use:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In class file:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

Context context;
GPSTracker gps;
Location location;
GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    gps = new GPSTracker(this);
    location = gps.getLocation();
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng((locLat + location.getLatitude()) / 2,
                    (locLng + location.getLongitude()) / 2), 12.0f));
}
```

Comment: Why you want to use `Activity` instead of `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: @VenomVendor I am using a library in which there is a class extending to Activity. I need to extend my activity to that class.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is:

- Put your map inside a fragment and in your activity inflate this fragment.

your xml code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="246dp" />
```

your java code to put in activity to inflate fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new MapFragment()).commit();
```

With this way you can implements Activity in your activity class and Fragment in your fragment class.

Comment: Ok... say the result later